# Cant transform json to listview in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, listview

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List items;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        'https://api.torn.com/torn/?selections=items&key=7PnSA9HkVB5B6eAK');

    this.setState(() {
      Map items = json.decode(response.body);
      print(items);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items == null ? 0 : items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            child: Text(items[index]['name']),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As far as i know we can get Json in two forms, first is List and second is a Map.
In my case i received a Map with all data i need but unfortunately i dont know how properly display that.
From print i received data but nothing happen on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You must not re-define items. You need to set it. It will look like this:

```
setState(() {
  items = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(items);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the setState inside your `getData` method, you are creating a new `items` variable instead of assigning the new value to it. Try this one.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Map items = {};
  Future<void> getData() async {
    http.Response res = await http.get(
      "https://api.torn.com/torn/?selections=items&key=7PnSA9HkVB5B6eAK",
    );
    setState(() => items = jsonDecode(res.body)["items"]);
    print(items);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          index++;
          return Card(
            child: Text(items[index.toString()]["name"] ?? "Empty"),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```